# LCP of KKT from a QP without non-negativity constraint and semidefinite Q matrix

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

Most formulations of the LCP derived from the KKT conditions of a QP tackle problems with non-negativity constraints $x\ge 0$. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complementarity_problem#:%7E:text=If%20the%20non%2Dnegativity%20constraint%20on%20the%20x%20is%20relaxed%2C%20the%20dimensionality%20of%20the%20LCP%20problem%20can%20be%20reduced%20to%20the%20number%20of%20the%20inequalities%2C%20as%20long%20as%20Q%20is%20non%2Dsingular%20(which%20is%20guaranteed%20if%20it%20is%20positive%20definite).) presents an alternative without the non-negative constraints but that requires the $Q$ matrix (from the quadratic objective) to be non-singular.

My question is: if one can only assume $Q$ to be positive *semi*definite, can we still formulate the problem as an LCP? If so, how?

I tried to find the LCP, but had no luck without assuming at least the existence of a left inverse of $Q$.